# Will the "generified" version of JTree (TreeModel, TreeNode, ...) be in JDK7?

Tags: java, generics, swing, jtree, java-7

I found out recently that `JList` (finally!) was "generified" in JDK7.

Why `JTree` and related classes/interfaces are not changed the same?

*It would be a huge improvement. Casting `Object` is going on one's nerves.*

*NOTE: The javadoc had not yet been updated, see [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) and [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was someone making proposals on the `swing-dev` mailing list. I don't think it is complete yet.

My understanding of why it hasn't been generified yet is:

- The API does not fit generics very well (exposing implementation and arrays, for instance).
- Across GUI code, generification brings surprisingly little benefit considered.
- Engineers at Oracle have more business-relevant priorities.